# Need help to identify this chip

Tags: identification, circuit-protection, over-voltage-protection

[image]

The input and output are both 3.3V so I think it may be a over voltage chip but I could not find the relevance chip.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [Texas Instruments TPS22965](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps22965.pdf) load switch.

[image]

[image]

[image]

(Source: [lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Power-Distribution-Switches_Texas-Instruments-TPS22965DSGR_C122837.html))